# html calling element in header comparison

Tags: html, css, inline

I have a navigation element in HTML, I can change it with external CSS, but I want to compare how to call it from inside the HTML,

so I got

```
<div id="header" class="row">
    <div id="logo" class="col_12">And the winner is<span>n't...</span></div> 
    <div id="navigation" class="row"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Synopsis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stills/Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos/clips</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

If i put on header

```
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I can change my list to show as navigation on CSS with

```
#navigation ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but now I want to compare, and call this element from inside the HTML

I use in the head, and comment CSS

```
<style>
#ul.navigation{display:inline-block;}
</style>
```

But I dont think im referencing the element right

Also how will I call this "inline-block" property for my list inside my actual html body? [inine style]

I see the CSS working fine, but I want to compare calling with style in the head and how to call it in the body,

I have seen examples for the 3 cases,

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

I see it working with paragraph, but will need more clarification to know how will work with my element?

thanks

Comment: In your style tag, you are using an id selector for the UL element. You should use #navigation ul instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put like this :

```
<style>
    #navigation ul li { 
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

With `#ul.navigation{display:inline-block;}` you are selecting the wrong element.

`ul.navigation` -> your `ul` element with class`navigation`. 
`#` stands for **ID**. So `#ul.navigation` isn't valid.

You probably meant `div#navigation` or even better  `div#navigation ul li` to select the `li` elements of the `ul` element that is the child of a `div` with **ID** "navigation".

Like this:

```
<style>
    div#navigation ul li { 
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUZxD/).

Comment: hi thanks, the first way works, but the second doesnt work in my style on the header

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css in this way..
  #navigation ul li